# 'Async Juggling' - What is it really asking me to do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, asynchronous

I'm learning Node.js through the `learnyounode` project.  I have completed the first few assignments and they all seemed reasonably straightforward.

Then, I got to the 'Async Juggling' one, and the assignment's description went completely over my head in terms of what I need to do.

The gist of it, is I need to write a Javascript that accepts 3 URLs as arguments, but that associates the correct response to the correct server.  The assignment itself notes that you cannot naively assume that things will be properly associated with the correct URL.

The (incorrect) code I came up with proved that restriction true:

```
var http = require('http');
var bl = require('bl');

var httpCallback = function(response) {
    var pipeHandler = function (err, data) {
        if(err)
            return console.error(err);

        console.log(data.toString());
    };  

    response.pipe(bl(pipeHandler));
};

var juggleAsyncConnections = function(connA, connB, connC) {
    http.get(connA, httpCallback);
    http.get(connB, httpCallback);
    http.get(connC, httpCallback);
};

juggleAsyncConnections(process.argv[2], process.argv[3], process.argv[4]);
```

The problem, and thus my **question**, is, what *is* the correct way to handle asynchronous connection juggling, and what are the underlying concepts I need to understand to do it correctly?

*Note: I've seen other questions, like "OMG why doesn't my solution work?"  I'm not asking that, I deliberately set out to see the 'naive' solution fail for myself.  I don't understand the underlying principles of why it doesn't work, or what principles actually do work.  Additionally, I'm not asking for someone to 'solve the problem for me.'  If the general algorithm can be explained, I can probably implement it on my own.*

Comment: _"Counting callbacks is one of the fundamental ways of managing async in Node."_ That's an important part of the puzzle right there.

Comment: Right, one I don't know how to interpret in a usable way.  If it's so important, what does it mean?

Comment: Keep a running tally on how many callbacks you get. You know you're looking at a fixed number of inputs, so look for that many outputs before printing to the screen.

Comment: Said that way, that makes much more sense to me.  Would you mind making that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Counting callbacks is one of the fundamental ways of managing async in Node. [...]

That's an important piece.

You know how many inputs there are (3), and, because of that, you know how many outputs there should be. Keep a running tally as responses come back, then check if you received the full set before printing to the screen. You also want to keep the original order in mind (now if there were only a datatype that had numeric indexes... :grin:).

Good luck!